# Iterate across columns in spark dataframe and calculate min max value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I want to iterate across the columns of dataframe in my Spark program and calculate min and max value. 
I'm new to Spark and scala and not able to iterate over the columns once I fetch it in a dataframe.

I have tried running the below code but it needs column number to be passed to it, question is how do I fetch it from dataframe and pass it dynamically and store the result in a collection.

```
val parquetRDD = spark.read.parquet("filename.parquet")

parquetRDD.collect.foreach ({ i => parquetRDD_subset.agg(max(parquetRDD(parquetRDD.columns(2))), min(parquetRDD(parquetRDD.columns(2)))).show()})
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be iterating on rows or records. You should be using aggregation function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.read.parquet("filename.parquet")
val aggCol = col(df.columns(2))
df.agg(min(aggCol), max(aggCol)).show()
```

First when you do spark.read.parquet you are reading a dataframe.
Next we define the column we want to work on using the col function. The col function translate a column name to a column. You could instead use df("name") where name is the name of the column.

The agg function takes aggregation columns so min and max are aggregation functions which take a column and return a column with an aggregated value.

**Update**

According to the comments, the goal is to have min and max for all columns. You can therefore do this:

```
val minColumns = df.columns.map(name => min(col(name)))
val maxColumns = df.columns.map(name => max(col(name)))
val allMinMax = minColumns ++ maxColumns
df.agg(allMinMax.head, allMinMax.tail: _*).show()
```

You can also simply do:

```
df.describe().show()
```

which gives you statistics on all columns including min, max, avg, count and stddev

Comment: Thanks Assaf for your response. But here in val aggCol = col(df.columns(2)) aren't we actually passing column number ( 2 in this case) manually. Is there a way that I can pass that dynamically, such that I could iterate over the columns one by one in a loop and generate min max. Thanks you.

Comment: Thanks Assaf ! it does help but can this be written in a loop such that I do not need to pass column name manually. When I say iterate in my question, I meant loop over the columns one by one.
In the below example, we have three columns and I would dynamically want to select each column, calculate its min max, without
having to pass the column name manually. Assume any random set of value for col1, col2, col3

col1  col2  col3