# Calculate min max using Spark dataframe and vertically align output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read the parquet file and generate the min max output in a 
    tabular format as shown below,

```
  **Required output**

column_name | min_value | max_value
:-----      | -----    :|:----:
  a         | 1         | 21
:-----      |------    :|:----:
  b         | 2         | 30
```

below code, I am able to read parquet file and generate min 
    max output for all columns but it is not as per the required format but 
    generated output is horizontally alined.

```
           //Read parquet file
val parquetRDD = spark.read.parquet("filename.parquet")

          //Calculate min and max value of columns
val minColumns = parquetRDD.columns.map(name => min(col(name)))

val maxColumns = parquetRDD.columns.map(name => max(col(name)))

val allMinMax = minColumns ++ maxColumns
         //Generate output 
val result = parquetRDD.agg(allMinMax.head, allMinMax.tail: _*).show()

  **Current Generated Output** 

min(a) | min(b) | max(a) | max(b)
:----- | -----: | ----:  | :----:
 1     | 2      | 21     |  30
```

Is there a way that I can put the generated output with proper 
      column names in the vertically alined format as shown in the Required 
      output section above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate across columns in spark dataframe and calculate min max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171920/iterate-across-columns-in-spark-dataframe-and-calculate-min-max-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find the min and max value of each column you can use [describe function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#describe-scala.collection.Seq-) ins spark sql, count mean and standard deviation

Here is the simple example, How ever it also generates

```
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq((1,2,3), (3,4,5), (1,2,4)).toDF("A", "B", "C")
df1.describe().show()
```

Output :

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+---+
|summary|                 A|                 B|  C|
+-------+------------------+------------------+---+
|  count|                 3|                 3|  3|
|   mean|1.6666666666666667|2.6666666666666665|4.0|
| stddev|1.1547005383792517|1.1547005383792517|1.0|
|    min|                 1|                 2|  3|
|    max|                 3|                 4|  5|
+-------+------------------+------------------+---+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Shankar ! you are awesome..this does help.I accept this answer. Can this code be extended to calculate other factors such as skewness, median, unique value, kurtosis etc.

Comment: yes you can calculate skewness and kurtosis, you can see here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10641